# R split apply combine with dplyr - how to keep NA resulting from slice

Tags: r, dplyr

```
mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% arrange(mpg) %>% slice(8)
```

outputs

```
    mpg   cyl
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  30.4     4
2  15.2     8
```

As you can see, it does not produce a row for 6 cylinders - what is the recommended way to keep all the groups, even if combine is empty?

Comment: I'm not sure it's ideal, but `mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% arrange(mpg) %>% summarise(mpg = mpg[8])` works.

Comment: Good question. Seems `slice` is designed to behave unlike `[]` elsewhere in R. Alistaire's solution is okay until you have more columns to work with, at which point you'll perhaps want to switch to data.table, with syntax like `DT[order(mpg), .SD[8L], by=cyl, .SDcols="mpg"]` ... well, I guess there's summarise_each/summarise_at, but those would fail to extend to, e.g., selecting both the seventh and eighth rows.

Comment: @Frank You can generalize it easily with `summarise_all`, e.g. `mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% arrange(mpg) %>% summarise_all(funs(.[8]))`

Comment: @alistaire Oh, good point. I didn't know summarise_all was a thing.

Comment: @alistaire Since nobody gives an answer, why don't you propose your generalized solution...

Comment: @SergeyAldoukhov Done. I added a way to select multiple rows, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quickly select a row from each group, keeping `NA`s, you can subset inside `summarise_all`:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
    arrange(mpg) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(.[8]))

## # A tibble: 3 × 11
##     cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     4  30.4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1     4     2
## 2     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 3     8  15.2 304.0   150  3.15 3.435 17.30     0     0     3     2
```

However, @Frank is right above; it won't extend nicely to subsetting to multiple rows in this format because `summarise` demands a single result row for each group. To subset, say, rows 7 and 8 of each group, use a list column and unnest with `tidyr::unnest`:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
    arrange(mpg) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(list(.[7:8]))) %>% 
    unnest()

## # A tibble: 6 × 11
##     cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     4  27.3  79.0    66  4.08 1.935 18.90     1     1     4     1
## 2     4  30.4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1     4     2
## 3     6  21.4 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
## 4     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 5     8  15.2 275.8   180  3.07 3.780 18.00     0     0     3     3
## 6     8  15.2 304.0   150  3.15 3.435 17.30     0     0     3     2
```

A more concise version with `purrr::dmap` returns the same thing:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
    arrange(mpg) %>% 
    dmap(~.x[7:8])
```

Comment: `dmap` has now moved to package `purrrlyr`

Answer (score 0):

Since *dplyr 0.8* we can use `group_map`, so with the same idea as @alistaire we can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% arrange(mpg)

mtcars2 %>% group_map(~.[8,]) 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  30.4
#> 2     6  NA  
#> 3     8  15.2

mtcars2 %>% group_map(~.[7:8,]) 
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  27.3
#> 2     4  30.4
#> 3     6  21.4
#> 4     6  NA  
#> 5     8  15.2
#> 6     8  15.2
```